# WaveOut to play wave file to specific channels of the device

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, waveout

I am using `WaveOut` API for playing the .wav file, using the device capability I am getting the device information. Is there any way to get the channel information (e.g. how the ASIO gives) and need to play two different .wav files to the two different channels of the device. Please help me in this regard. Any C# samples would be helpful

Best Regards,
Ramachandran

Answer (score 0):

The waveOut API only accepts interleaved samples for the different channels, so you will have to merge the 2 single channel files into a dual channel file and play that.